# Insertar una imagen dentro de un .rtf con c#

Tags: c#, rtf

Estoy intentando insertar imágenes en posiciones concretas de un fichero .rtf, para ello de momento estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
sw.Write("{\\sv{\\pict\\jpegblip\\picw2646\\pich2646\\picwgoal1500\\pichgoal1500\\picscalex100\\picscaley100\\piccropl0\\piccropr0\\piccropt0\\piccropb0\\bliptag1784904213{\\*\\blipuid");
            do
            {
                buffer = reader.ReadBytes(100000);
                sw.Write(Convert.ToHexString(buffer));
            }
            while (buffer.Length == 100000);
            sw.Write("}}}}");
```

Dentro del bucle do while se está metiendo la imagen en binario a trozos mediante un buffer, esa parte debe estar bien, sin embargo lo que parece no funcionar es el formato de la imagen. Este viene dado por los sw.Write("...") que hay antes y después del bucle.

Dicho de otra forma lo que estoy haciendo es esto

-Insertar formato de la imagen
-Insertar binario de la imagen
-Insertar fin del formato de la imagen

Pero al abrir el rtf generado sale algo como esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me imagino que habla de "tablas dañadas" ya que la imagen se está metiendo dentro de la tabla, y hay algo en el formato de la imagen que estoy aplicando que interfiere con las tablas.

Mi pregunta entonces es, como debe formatearse una imagen para poder insertarla al .rtf. He buscado en un montón de sitios y no he encontrado nada que me sirva.